# Yocto has error when compiling raspi kernel with the 'bcm2709_defconfig'

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi2, yocto

I add `KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_myrpi2 = "bcm2709_defconfig"` in my kernel recipe to use "In-Tree" defconfig file. I compile the kernel use command:

```
bitbake -c compile linux-rpi2
```

but it outputs some errors, here is the log:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 2 zImage CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd  
  GEN     ./Makefile
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  GEN     ./Makefile
  UPD     include/config/kernel.release
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/bitsperlong.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/cputime.h
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/current.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/emergency-restart.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/errno.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/exec.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/ioctl.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/ipcbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/irq_regs.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/kdebug.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/local.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/local64.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/mm-arch-hooks.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/msgbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/msi.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/param.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/parport.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/poll.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/preempt.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/bin2c
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/resource.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/rwsem.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/seccomp.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/sections.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/segment.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/sembuf.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/serial.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/shmbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/siginfo.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/simd.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/sizes.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/socket.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/sockios.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/termbits.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/termios.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/timex.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/trace_clock.h
  WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/unaligned.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  Using /home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source as source for kernel
  Generating include/generated/mach-types.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  UPD     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  UPD     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    /home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/checks.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/util.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.hash.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.o
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.h
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/pnmtologo
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  HOSTCC  usr/gen_init_cpio
  CC      init/main.o
  GEN     usr/initramfs_data.cpio
  AS      usr/initramfs_data.o
  LD      usr/built-in.o
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.o
  CC      init/initramfs.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/entry.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/vfphw.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpsingle.o
  CC      init/calibrate.o
  CC      init/init_task.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpdouble.o
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      arch/arm/vfp/vfp.o
  LD      arch/arm/vfp/built-in.o
  LD      init/mounts.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/elf.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/irq.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/opcodes.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/extable.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/process.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/fault.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/init.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/iomap.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/reboot.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/return_address.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/nommu.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/setup.o
  CC      arch/arm/mm/proc-syms.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/abort-ev7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/pabort-v7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.o
  LD      arch/arm/mm/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/signal.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/sigreturn_codes.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/stacktrace.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/time.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/traps.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/fiq.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/fiqasm.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/armksyms.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/module.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/arch_timer.o
  CC      arch/arm/common/firmware.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/jump_label.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/insn.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/patch.o
  LD      arch/arm/common/built-in.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/decode.o
In file included from /home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:8:0:
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c: In function 'patch_map':
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:25:29: error: 'L_PTE_YOUNG' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON (L_PTE_YOUNG | L_PTE_PRESENT | L_PTE_XN | L_PTE_DIRTY)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:29: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON'
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:25:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON (L_PTE_YOUNG | L_PTE_PRESENT | L_PTE_XN | L_PTE_DIRTY)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:29: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON'
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:25:43: error: 'L_PTE_PRESENT' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON (L_PTE_YOUNG | L_PTE_PRESENT | L_PTE_XN | L_PTE_DIRTY)
                                           ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:29: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON'
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:25:59: error: 'L_PTE_XN' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON (L_PTE_YOUNG | L_PTE_PRESENT | L_PTE_XN | L_PTE_DIRTY)
                                                           ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:29: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON'
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:25:70: error: 'L_PTE_DIRTY' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON (L_PTE_YOUNG | L_PTE_PRESENT | L_PTE_XN | L_PTE_DIRTY)
                                                                      ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:29: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON'
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                             ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/include/asm/fixmap.h:27:50: error: 'L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL (FIXMAP_PAGE_COMMON | L_PTE_MT_WRITEBACK)
                                                  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/include/asm-generic/fixmap.h:64:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL'
  __set_fixmap(idx, phys, FIXMAP_PAGE_NORMAL)
                          ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/arch/arm/kernel/patch.c:39:2: note: in expansion of macro 'set_fixmap'
  set_fixmap(fixmap, page_to_phys(page));
  ^
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel/patch.o' failed
make[3]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/patch.o] Error 1
/home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work-shared/myrpi2/kernel-source/Makefile:959: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/kernel] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      arch/arm/probes/decode-arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/core.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/actions-common.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/checkers-common.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/actions-arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/checkers-arm.o
  CC      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/opt-arm.o
  LD      arch/arm/probes/kprobes/built-in.o
  LD      arch/arm/probes/built-in.o
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:24: recipe for target '__sub-make' failed
make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/max/project/yocto-build/tmp/work/myrpi2-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-rpi2/4.4.23+gitAUTOINC+844d3dfedc-r0/temp/log.do_compile.5822)
```

However when I cross compile the kernel manually there is no problem with it.